# Save using Jquery UI modal popup

Tags: visualforce, jquery, button, custom-controller, popup

I have a Jquery UI modal popup that is basically an iframe with a VF page within. The VF page requires the user to enter some data and either click SAVE or CANCEL.

The problem is that if I use custom SAVE and CANCEL buttons on the VF page then they don't let me close the popup (possibly because I do not have an id of the iframe to close it) and if I use SAVE and CANCEL buttons on the iframe then I am unable to fetch the data entered on the VF page to the iframe and then pass it to the VF controller, i.e., the SAVE is not working.

here is the Jquery code for the popup:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/js/functions.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/ui/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/postmessage/jquery.ba-postmessage.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/bbq/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js')} 
requireCssFile('/resource/jQueryForPopup/jQuery/ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css'); 

function requireCssFile(filename) 
{ 
var fileref = document.createElement('link'); 
fileref.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet'); 
fileref.setAttribute('type', 'text/css'); 
fileref.setAttribute('href', filename); 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref); 
} 

var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
var iframe_url = '{! URLFOR('/apex/Add_address', null, ['id' = Member__c.Id]) }'; 
console.log('keith'+iframe_url); 
var j$modalDialog = j$('<div id="opppopup"></div>') 
.html('<iframe id="iframeContentId" src="' + iframe_url + '" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" />') 
.dialog({ 
autoOpen: false, 
title: 'Add Details', 
resizable: true, 
width: 800, 
height: 540, 
autoResize: true, 
modal: true, 
draggable: true, 
buttons: { 
"Cancel": function() { 
j$modalDialog.dialog('close'); 
}, 
"Save": { text:'Save', 
click: function () { 
var iframe_url = '{! URLFOR('/apex/Add_address', null, ['id' = BP__c.Id]) }'; 
console.log('check: '+iframe_url); 

j$modalDialog.dialog('close'); 
} 
}} 
}); 

j$modalDialog.dialog('open');
```

Here Add_address is the name of the VF page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why are you using iframes ? did you try directly show the visualforce page in a popup ?

Comment: using iframe for the better look and feel of the popup.. (avoiding use of css)